Determine best Python-NetworkX graph architecture for automobiles with error codes
I am a mechanic and have 200 or so cars. Each car has error codes I want to graph. And ultimately visualize and compare similar automobiles based on their error codes. Do I create nodes named Car 1, Car 2 ... Car N... etc., and then create edges as a list of their respective error codes? And only have edges connecting the nodes if they have error codes in common? Then, how do I compare them? Say, Car 1 has error code 1, 2 and 3 and Car 2 has error code 2, 3 and 4? How do I compare them on a graph?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

I would rather make a Venn diagramm using venn2_worldcloud (by @PaulBrodersen) :
from matplotlib_venn_wordcloud import venn2_wordcloud

data = {
    "Car 1": {1, 2, 3},
    "Car 2": {2, 3, 4},
}  # or any equivalent input

def cmp(errs, c1, c2, freqs=None, **kwargs):
    venn2_wordcloud(
        sets=[
            set(map(str, e))
            for e in (errs[c1], errs[c2])
        ],
        set_labels=[c1, c2],
        set_colors=["cyan", "red"],
        **kwargs,
    )

cmp(data, "Car 1", "Car 2")


But if you insist to go with networkx, you could use draw_labeled_multigraph :
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

data = {
    "Car 1": {1, 2, 3},
    "Car 2": {2, 3, 4},
    "Car 3": {5, 1},
    "Car 4": {3},
} # with more cars ..

G = nx.MultiGraph(
    [
        (c1, c2, {"error": e})
        for (c1, e1), (c2, e2) in combinations(data.items(), 2)
        for e in e1 & e2
    ]
)

draw_labeled_multigraph(G, "error")


